# Macro highlighting changes in cells with range constantly changing

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following macro in order to highlight any changes in a particular range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Tracking Changes In Yellow
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("L12", Range("L12").End(xlDown))
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
           Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
```

The macro is running perfectly with the exception of when I input a new value into a cell beyond the chart area, which I can't have and it is causing me issues since I am using the range `Range("L12", Range("L12").End(xlDown)`.

As you can see in the picture, if I input a new value right under it, it will highlight it yellow due to `End(xlDown)` but not if I do it two cells away. What is the best way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Why not just use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Yes. good idea to use conditional formatting. I believe something else is required apart from that function

Comment: Can you use conditional formatting to highlight when someone makes a change in the cell? Essentially cells that are highlighted yellow will be filtered, used to make changes in another sheet, and then reset back to white so that if it is changed again it will update again.

Comment: The short answer is yes, but having that "color switching back and forth" type feature will require some workarounds.  You should do some web searching on conditional formatting, there are many many results on this robust feature.  Consider that this feature is highly dependent on your version, so find appropriate info for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your need.  If it will always be in the J column then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Tracking Changes In Yellow
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("L12", Range("L" & Rows.Count))
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
           Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Essentially cells that are highlighted yellow will be filtered, used to make changes in another sheet, and then reset back to white so that if it is changed again it will update again. My fear is that someone other than me will make a change outside of the chart area, which will then be filtered in since I am filtering by color.

Comment: You're introducing a set of other problems not in the original concern."Someone other than me" is a challenging concern, there are solutions but you should address that as a distinct question.  Changing the color of the cell based on multiple criteria should also be addressed distinctly.  Consider this community as a group of people who will help you on specific concerns, to help you learn and solve problems, and please avoid "scope creep".  Please reward your answerers with upvotes and flag answers as such, and if you have additional questions, submit a new post after you do some research.